# Exit without losing cached output

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to add to a program I am writing, a feature whereby everything printed to the console, also gets added to a log file. This much can be done with broadcast streams. The problem is that the program may also need to abruptly exit from within a leaf function, and when I do this, the log file does not get created. This is what I have so far:

```
(catch 'quit
  (with-open-file (log-stream "log.txt" 
                   :direction :output 
                   :if-exists :supersede 
                   :if-does-not-exist :create)
    (let ((*standard-output*
            (make-broadcast-stream *standard-output* log-stream)))
      (format t "abc~%")
      (throw 'quit nil))))
```

When I run the above code (SBCL 1.4.2, Windows 7), the file `log.txt` does not get created. The same is true if I replace `(throw 'quit nil)` with `(quit)`. However, if I remove that line altogether and just let the program exit by falling off the end of the file, the log file does get correctly created, which suggests it's a caching issue.

Is that the correct diagnosis? If so, is there a way to tell the compiler not to cache that file, or to exit with rather than without writing cached data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the behaviour described in the standard for [`WITH-OPEN-FILE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_open.htm):

> If a new output file is being
>   written, and control leaves abnormally, the file is aborted and the file system is left, 
>   so far as possible, as if the file had never been opened.

The following explicitly closes the file:

```
(catch 'quit
  (with-open-file (log-stream "/tmp/log.txt" 
                   :direction :output 
                   :if-exists :supersede 
                   :if-does-not-exist :create)
    (let ((*standard-output* (make-broadcast-stream *standard-output* log-stream)))
      (unwind-protect (progn
                        (format t "abc~%")
                        (throw 'quit nil))
        (finish-output)
        (close log-stream :abort nil)))))
```

The `:abort nil` value is the default one, it is made explicit here for the sake of the answer.